# Geofencing (Leave/Enter geofence Timing) Issue?

Tags: algorithm, geofencing

I already search SE already if the question has been raised before but I can't find one so I'll ask here anyway. I'm creating a small application which involve geofencing my GPS device doesn't have a geofencing capability on it's own which I hope it has this feature for accuracy and ease of programming.

I have no choice to do it on the server level, my question is since my device is sending NMEA/GPRMC on a two minute interval is there an algorithm that we can use to detect the exact timing the vehicle leave or enter the geofence?

my current code can detect the vehicle inside/outside the geofence area no matter what type of polygon it's just the timing issue I can't solve.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it you can do this in a deterministic way. Your only option would be to predict near future based on other factors. for example:

1. movement history of your object
2. road network condition
3. traffic

However, the estimation won't be 100% probable. Consider a situation like this:

[image]

The car in the next couple of minutes can go into any direction at the intersection. So we cannot say it will absolutely enter my Geofencing polygon. To reduce the time error for Geofencing, you have to decrease the time frequency of GPS data collection.

Comment: That's what I thought so too, thanks for confirming it I'm just trying to exhaust everything since this is uncharted waters for me :) I'm fully satisfied now much appreciate it.

Comment: I am happy to hear that. consider marking as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having implemented something similar in postgres, I'll share what was implemented on our end.The goal was to detect when a tracking device enters a geofence, how long it dwells inside and when it exits the geofence.

Since you've already got a system to define the polygon and check if the current position is inside or outside, I'll go to the timing section.

Consider 3 states, entry, dwelling and exit. This could be 0,1,2. Every time the point is inside the polygon, the state will have to be saved somewhere. I'm not sure what kind of GPS device you're using, this can be implemented using files, in-ram (if you have lots of RAM ofc) or a small database internally if you have the option.

Considering 2 tables, 1st to hold interactions and 2nd to hold states.

First one to hold interactions

```
ID | deviceID | polygonID | state | timestamp
```

Second one to hold states example

```
ID | deviceID | polygonID | entry_timestamp | exit_timestamp | dwelling_duration
```

**Logic**

For every location point, you'll need to query if the point is inside any polygon and process the data per polygon returned.

- Is the current lat,lon from the device inside any polygon?

  - No : Is the previous lat,lon inside any polygon?

    - Yes: Insert exit along with timestamp (State 2)
    - No : Continue to end of the loop
  - Yes : Query the point again if it has a previous interaction

    - Yes : Since the point has an interaction earlier, the device seems to be inside the geofence dwelling. Make an insert in your database to record the instance as state 1
    - No : Sine the point has no interaction earlier, the device seems to be entering the geofence for the 1st time. Make an insert in your database to record the instance as state 0.

Once an interaction is complete, you'll get data somewhat like this

ID | deviceID | polygonID | state | timestamp

1. -----1-----| -----1------ | ---0----| 1548132074
2. -----1-----| -----1------ | ---1----| 1548142074
3. -----1-----| -----1------ | ---1----| 1548152074
4. -----1-----| -----1------ | ---1----| 1548162074
5. -----1-----| -----1------ | ---2----| 1548172074

From the above, id-1 has your entry timestamp, id-5 has your exit timestamp and you can calculate your dwelling duration from id-1 timestamp till id-5 timestamp.

This depends on the accuracy of the GPS device, for GPS-errors a filtering system will have to be implemented in the algorithm itself.

I hope this helps.